# Showing Interstitial ad on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I referred to [AdsPCLXamarin](https://github.com/sharker86/AdsPCLXamarin) for showing banner ads on Xamarin.Forms. But I need to show Interstitial ads.

so far, with my custom renderer for Android, i've done this:

**Control class:**

```
public class MyInterstitial:View
{
}
```

**Renderer:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyInterstitial), typeof(CustomInterstitialRenderer))]

namespace AdsPCL.Droid
{
    public class CustomInterstitialRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                var interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this.Context);
                interstitialAd.AdUnitId = "MY KEY";
                var requestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

                interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestBuilder);
                
                this.SetNativeControl(interstitialAd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Banner ads, the last step was `this.SetNativeControl(adViewObject);`

However, `this.SetNativeControl(interstitialAd);` is not working because of type mismatch.

Can someone show me the right way for Android? Would really appreciate if I can get the same for iOS, WinPhone

Comment: We'll need more code (how you declared renderer and control class)

Comment: @DanielLuberda, the control class is just extension of `View`.
I've added its code and the renderer's too.

The renderer for Banner Ads is working
https://github.com/sharker86/AdsPCLXamarin/blob/AdsPCL/AdsPCL/AdsPCL.Android/CustomBannerRenderer.cs

Comment: It's because InterstitialAd is not a view. You should implement it as a dependency service instead.

Comment: Yes, I thought i would have to put it in a `View` and then display it. Oliver's project shows how to do it using Dependancy service. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had implemented this solution for Xamarin Forms for viewing AdMob, including interstitials.

https://github.com/ioliver85/Xamarin.Admob

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking it needed a custom renderer and then I would have to show the ad using `AbsoluteLayout`.
This is great, just have to call the service and the ad pops!

Comment: are you planning to add WinPhone/WP8.1 ? If not, let me know how to add the project, I've already written it for WinPhone; will add it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Is simply, you clone the project from github https://github.com/ioliver85/Xamarin.Admob.git and you implement the new functionality and later you will do a "pull request" and I will add your code in the repository.

Comment: Yes, but how do I add the `Xamarin.WinPhone` project to the solution

Comment: You create a new portable library in the solution with Xamarin, you add the Xamarin.Forms library and implements the solution. You can see this documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/

Comment: wow this library seems to be super old. nuget packages arent even available. I think that there is now firebase nuget for admob ads.